# ImportError: cannot import name 'ratio' from 'Levenshtein' (unknown location)

Tags: levenshtein-distance

When I try `import fuzzymatcher` I get the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ratio' from 'Levenshtein' (unknown location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line `#include <Python.h>`  to first line of the file `_levenshtein.c` inside of the Levenshtein folder.

Then in fuzzywuzzy folder, replace `from .StringMatcher import StringMatcher as SequenceMatcher` with `from Levenshtein import *`.

Comment: how did you find the solution ?